# Is it coincidental that matrices are useful for solving systems of equations or is there a deeper (geometric) connection?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have this simple system of equations:

$$-x + y = 1$$
$$ x + y = 3$$

They intersect at the point $(1,2)$ and this is the graph:
[image]

One way of going about and solving this system of equations is to convert it into matrix form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
3
\end{bmatrix}$$

When my brain sees this matrix form, it has the following **geometric meaning**: If we apply the linear transformation encoded by $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ to vector $\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}$, then the output vector is $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
3
\end{bmatrix}$.
We can then use Gaussian Elimination to determine $\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}$.

**My question:** Is the matrix form of the system of equations simply a useful trick to algorithmically solve these systems of equations use Elementary Row Operations, etc. Or is there a deeper geometric connection between the intersection of two lines and the linear transformation of the vector that describes said intersection.

Comment: Aren't matrices defined with the purpose of solving linear equations? They are just a rewriting of the problem. I wouldn't even call it a trick.

Comment: Is that true? I thought matrices (in linear algebra) were defined as a notation for describing linear combinations of vectors.

Comment: No. Initially the matrices were invented for solving the systems of linear equations.

Comment: You should think of matrices as a linear map. If $A$ is a matrix and $v$ is a vector, there's a formula for the coordinates of $Av$. Try to see what comes out if $A$ is the 2 by 2 matrix you wrote down and $v = (x,y)^T$!

Comment: Though disregarding the formalities, it never stops *feeling* miraculous from time to time...

Comment: I think the geometry is that affine hyperplanes in a vector space naturally correspond to affine lines in its dual space. A single non-zero equation (up to scaling) describes the kernel of such an affine line in dual space, which is precisely the associated affine hyperplane. Putting multiple equations together corresponds to the intersection of these hyperplanes on one hand and to taking the product of the functionals on the other hand.

Comment: Highly recommend 3blue1brown’s Essence of Linear Algebra, for some geometric intuition. https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab

Comment: It is my impression that "matrices" (blocks of numbers or symbols) historically first represented "determinants", which had an existence prior to "linear algebra", or the linear algebra understanding of systems of linear equations. And it was only a bit later (later 19th centurey) that the notation and concept were seen to connect meaningfully to solution of linear equations. E.g., apparently finite-dimensional linear algebra came _after_ the discussion of compact operators on Hilbert spaces...

Comment: A few comments have said matrices were introduced in order to solve linear systems of equations.
I think Paul Garret has the correct history. Disregardingg history, in my mind matrices exist first and foremost in order to describe linear transformations.

Answer (score 2):

You are right: matrices can be thought of as representing linear transformations. An $(m \times n)$-matrix takes as inputs vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space and outputs vectors in an $m$-dimensional vector space. The crucial observation here is that in order to completely determine a linear transformation $T: V \to V'$, it suffices to know what it does on a certain chosen basis $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ of $V$, since for any other $v \in V$, writing $v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i e_i$ means that we have to get $T(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i T(e_i)$. Still the $T(e_i)$ are vectors, but we would like to express these using numbers as well. So we chooose another basis $\{e_1', \dots, e_m'\}$ of $V'$, so that we can write any vector $v' \in V'$ as a linear combination of the $e_i'$. In particular, there are certain numbers $T_{ij}$ such that we have $T(e_i) = \sum_{j = 1}^m T_ij e_j'$. We conveniently put all these $n \cdot m$ numbers in a rectangular shape because it makes calculations easier, and tadá: we get our usual matrix notation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've got a potential explanation. The key is my realization that an equation can be thought of geometrically as a linear transformation of space.

Let's take our first equation: $$ -x + y = 1$$
This can be rewritten in "linear algebra" form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} *\begin{bmatrix}
x  \\
y  
\end{bmatrix} = 1$$

This form is saying that if we apply the
linear transformation encoded by $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ to a 2D vector $\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}$, then the 1D output "vector" is $\begin{bmatrix}
1
\end{bmatrix}$.

As it turns out, there are an infinite amount of 2D vectors that will satisfy the above expression. These vectors form the line described by our first equation.

Now when we add the second equation into our system, the question becomes: **Is there a vector that satisfies BOTH linear transformations encoded by their respective equations?** Indeed, the graphical intersection of these lines is that very vector.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but thinking of equations as linear transformations of space is a beautiful example of *duality* in mathematics.

Comment: You can also think of $Ax = b$ as expressing $b$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$. There is a solution to $Ax = b$ if and only if $b$ is in the column space of $A$.